# Add timer to a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a timer rather than a countdown which automatically starts when 
the form loads. Starting time should be 45 minutes and once it ends, i.e. on reaching 0 minutes, the form should terminate with a message displayed.  How can I do this?

Language: preferably C#.

Comment: Personally, I enjoy being able to help with homework. The key word being *help*. So why are we *doing* someone's homework without some reasonable attempt at showing us an effort?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Bit more detail:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (45 * 60 * 1000); // 45 mins
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The form will now be closed.", "Time Elapsed");
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: hey bro thanx a lot...it worked....
actually i m a fresher in prog so i would really appreciate if u explain me how it works.especially these two lines: 
MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
MyTimer.Start();

and why 1000??i.e in 45*60*1000....
and i want to display the time(countdown) display in a label or somthn like dat on the form...
thanx

Comment: MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);

The timer has an event called Tick when the set interval elapses. In this case, we are saying that we want to invoke the MyTimer_Tick method when the tick event occurs.

MyTimer.Interval = (45 * 60 * 1000);

The interval of the timer is in milliseconds and thus I used a calculation rather than just working out the answer and sticking in the value. I think this makes it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: thanx...i got it...bt wat about displaying the countdown at the form??

Comment: If you want to display countdown then you have to use timer with higher granularity (eg. 1 second or 1 minute, depending on what you expect) and handle the logic inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this in your form main. Double click the form in the visual editor to create the form load event.

```
 Timer Clock=new Timer();
 Clock.Interval=2700000; // not sure if this length of time will work 
 Clock.Start();
 Clock.Tick+=new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
```

Then add an event handler to do something when the timer fires.

```
  public void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs eArgs)
  {
    if(sender==Clock)
    {
      // do something here      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -11):

Download http://download.cnet.com/Free-Desktop-Timer/3000-2350_4-75415517.html

Then add a button or something on the form and inside its event, just open this app
ie:

{

Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Free Desktop Timer\DesktopTimer");

}

Comment: This is a terrible solution... download a 3rd party Timer, pffft. Why wouldn't you use the standard Timer control? Are you the author of this component?

Comment: I'm a beginner.. But actually how is it possible to display the timer control during a runtime? like the third party timer... pls answer if u know..

Comment: Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)         Dim diff As New TimeSpan()         diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)         lblTime.Text = diff.Hours & ":" & diff.Minutes.ToString("00") & ":" & diff.Seconds.ToString("00")         lblTime.Invalidate()     End Sub

Comment: In Visual studio winforms, C#?

Comment: Meh, you didn't even thank me for providing the VB.Net code.

Comment: Sorry for that cos I haven't tried VB ever... Thanks anyways ;)