# C# ren function every 10 seconds in windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, timer

I have a software that reads data from my router.

Everything is working - but I have to press a buton called "refresh" if I want to see the data refreshing...

This should work in the background after I have connected to the device.

How can I do it automatically - every 10 seconds?

I have tried this:
[Add timer to a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142828/add-timer-to-a-windows-forms-application)

It seems my code doesn't know `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class.

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/266589-timer-ambiguous

Comment: Add Form. or Timers. befroe timer definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving an ambiguous reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141043/resolving-an-ambiguous-reference)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer class
> ```

```
private Timer timer1; 
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 10000; // 10 seconds / 10000 MillSecs
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isonline();
}
```

Thanks to Stecya in [Execute specified function every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169288/execute-specified-function-every-x-seconds)

Comment: Its seem I don't have System.Windows.Forms.Timer??  can it be ?

Comment: @David12123 Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Add reference... and then find System.Windows.Forms and add it.

When Windows.Forms is added you can use the Timer class.

Comment: the all c# code is a windows application form (and working) , but when I write this line  "using System.Windows.Forms.Timer" it say Timer is type not a namespace

Comment: @David12123 change it to `using System.Windows.Forms;` instead. But it sounds like you're running a console app, if that's not already available. If that's the case you probably should use one of the *other* `Timer` classes instead

Comment: I don't ,this is a windows forom application......  I found solution here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98c200lL-OY