# Application not launching without part being commented (Solved)

Tags: c#, game-engine, game-development

I am making an engine for my game and I have this bit of code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    GameTime.stopwatch.Start();
    if (GameTime.stopwatch.IsRunning)
    {
        GameTime.CallUpdate();
    }
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

and if I don't comment out either the stopwatch.Start() or the if statement, or if I just have GameTime.CallUpdate(), no application window pops up. It does not matter which I comment out, it just doesn't have a window if both are uncommented. If anyone can help me fix the issue of the app window not launching when I run the code uncommented please let me know.

Edit: Neither CallUpdate and stopwatch are part of LAUNCHING the window, which adds to my confusion

```
public static void CallUpdate()
{
    Debug.Write("I am here");
    while (stopwatch.IsRunning)
    {
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 120)
        {
            timeSinceUpdate = (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Debug.Write("Updated");
            //Call update
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  what application window is supposed to pop up?  Is ```GameTime.CallUpdate();``` supposed to make this application window pop up?  There's really not much to go on with that limited amount of code and explanation.  Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: From the information you've presented it appears that the problem lies in GameTime.CallUpdate(), but you haven't given us much to go on to understand what that function is doing. I have a hunch that you're blocking the UI thread, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You may also want to choose a better title for your question. The title is the bit of information on which users decide whether they want to have a look at your question.

Comment: Please take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mre], to learn how the site works before you begin posting. I don't know what you're referring to when you say *last time*,  because you created your account today and this is your only question, but if you had a previous account that you had issues with, you apparently have not yet learned from your mistakes.

Comment: 'What is going on?' is not a title that summarizes the problem. Please choose a better title.

Comment: OnLoad has to **return** in order for your application to launch and for the window to be shown.  But yours doesn't return, it stays in a while loop in `CallUpdate`.  The better way to do this is to use a `Timer` component to have a function be called on a recurring interval.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142828/add-timer-to-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking into the subject of *threading* in C#. All of the code you provided runs on a single thread which also happens to be the UI thread.

When you uncomment `GameTime.stopwatch.Start();`, it makes the value of `stopwatch.IsRunning` to be always `true`, so the loop `while (stopwatch.IsRunning)` runs infinitely. Because of that `CallUpdate` method never finishes execution and base `base.OnLoad(e);` is never called and your window never shown.

A trivial example how to solve this would be using `Task.Run`, e.g.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        GameTime.stopwatch.Start();
        if (GameTime.stopwatch.IsRunning)
        {
            GameTime.CallUpdate();
        }
    });
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

This task executes the code inside it asynchronously on another thread and will not block `base.OnLoad(e);`. However, you still have an infinite loop on that asynchronous thread and you'll have to stop the stopwatch somewhere in order for the `CallUpdate` method to complete.

Also, threading, introduces a significant amount of complexity to deal with. For example most platforms require a technique called *synchronization* when attempting to update a UI element from a non-UI thread.

Perhaps, using a simple `Timer` class instead, might be enough in your case. All depends on what you plan to do with your `GameTime`.

Comment: I appreciate you assistance, and as for GameTime is similar to Unity's Time class in relativity, containing the time between updates and several other time related things. So once again thank you for your solution and appreciate your aide.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think my answer is helpful, I would appreciate upvoting it and marking it as the accepted answer. Should anyone give you a better answer, you can always change this decision later. Have fun coding your game, cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `base.OnLoad(e)` until `GameTime.CallUpdate()` returns.

But the `CallUpdate()` method never returns. The loop in that method runs until the stopwatch is not running, but nothing ever tells it to stop.  Is it possible that rather than calling `stopwatch.Restart()` you should be calling `stopwatch.Stop()`?